# Burninate [embedded-code]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[embedded-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-code) says "For questions on code embedded in web pages. Not for embedded development; use just the plain tag [embedded] for that." I would suppose this tag was created by someone who got tired of people constantly misusing the [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) tag.

However, looking at the 41 questions with this tag, roughly 90% is about embedded systems programming. The tag has clearly failed to deliver. I'm not convinced that we actually need a tag "code embedded in web pages" either, since the tag is barely ever used - the tag is 8 years old! Remove the embedded systems questions from it and there's not much left.

Since there's only 41 questions, I can go ahead and clean this up myself, but I'm posting here first in case someone has a better idea than to simply remove the tag.

---

EDIT: I think there are too few questions to bother with the formal burnination procedure. However, the following does apply:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tag is ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes it is.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not as far as I can tell, other than where it incorrectly serves as a place-holder for [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded).

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Not at all.

Comment: Note that "This tag is hardly ever used" is not a good argument to burn a tag, instead an argument should be made as to why it's harmful in its current state.

Comment: To remove a tag you have to justify that it doesn't belong to the site. If people use badly the tag only because it's a name problem, then rename the tag, for instance `web-embedded-code`

Comment: @Adriaan "This tag is hardly ever used _correctly_" is rather the argument here.

Comment: I think it should be a clean-up request, not a burnination request

Comment: If a tag for code embedded in pages in needed, then i think it needs renamed.  When I saw this question title, my first thought was it was about embedded systems as well.  No idea what a new name should be, but in its current state, it is ambiguous

Comment: FWIW, I count [about 20 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-code+-embedded+-c+-microcontroller+-firmware+-avr+-msp430+-stm32) that seem to be using the tag more or less as intended. Still not convinced that it's actually a useful tag, but I'd say your "roughly 90%" misuse rate is a bit exaggerated.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I suppose most of the "JS in HTML" questions could be moved to the existing [tag:inline-scripting] tag. (We also have [tag:inline-code], but that's also ambiguous and in need of cleanup.) The PHP / ASP questions could fit under [tag:templates], if that tag wasn't an even worse mess. :P I'm not convinced that those questions actually need anything but the relevant language tags, though.

Comment: Was this cleaned up sometime? Seems like there are 22 posts remaining and most of them are valid posts

Comment: @BhargavRao Nope, the thread didn't get enough interest - maybe someone started cleaning but stopped half-ways. But I can chew through those 22 posts quick enough. I'll start it again.

Comment: Thanks for that. :-) ... (there's now a resurgent interest in burnination requests, feel free to catch up and update any other requests which you've posted early on).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If you have authoritative knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help.

Proposed course of action for all questions with this tag:

- All questions regarding embedded systems programming should get re-tagged to [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded).
- All questions regarding embedding code in web sites drop the tag and instead use the relevant language tags (JavaScript, HTML etc).
- All questions regarding embedding "stuff into other stuff", such as embedding code in non-web applications, should drop the tag and get reviewed on case-by-case basis.

All of this should of course follow the usual re-tagging procedure, where other problems with the questions should be addressed at the same time.

If someone else with reasonably "authoritative knowledge" of either embedded systems or web programming agrees, then I'll go ahead and start cleaning this.

---

**EDIT**

The tag has been burninated as per 2018-06-25, using the informal burninate procedure [described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

Comment: As a developer of embedded systems, this sounds reasonable to me:)

Comment: I consider myself an expert in this field, too. I agree with your procedure and support burnination of the tag to quick way (no need for full bureaucracy).